# Mongoid query records that have all their embedded documents matching a criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have models like this

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :producer, type: String
  embedded_in :band
end
```

What I want to get is all bands that have all their albums produced by "George Martin".

I tried `Band.where('albums.producer' => 'George Martin')` but it's matching all bands which have at least once George Martin in their producers.

Examples:

This band should match (because all their albums have been produced by George Martin):

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("blabla"),
  "albums" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e0"),
      "name" : "Violator",
      "producer" : "George Martin"
    }
  ]
}
```

This band shouldn't match (because the album "+" has been produced by another producer):

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("blablabla"),
  "albums" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("album1"),
      "name" : "/",
      "producer" : "George Martin"
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("album2"),
      "name" : "+",
      "producer" : "Another producer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to process your `albums` array. By setting an initial value of `true`, you can conditionally set the value to `false` when one entry is not equal to
"George Martin" by using `$and` condition with the accumulator. `$match` the final result of the accumulator to perform the filtering.

```
{
    "$reduce": {
        "input": "$albums",
        "initialValue": true,
        "in": {
        $and: [
            "$$value",
            {
            $eq: [
                "$$this.producer",
                "George Martin"
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MIE_H-gfmYO) for your reference.

Comment: That looks to be what I want! See the mongoid aggregation section to translate. Also what kind of index is required for large DBs?

Comment: It depends on your query pattern. You may want to check out [this MongoDB official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes).